# How to make SVG viewBox consistent across devices?

Tags: reactjs, svg

I am using SVG component in my app.
SVG:

```
<div id="twinklingstars">
    <svg id="sky" viewBox = "0 0 400 650">
    {[...Array(num)].map((x, y) => (
        <circle
            cx={this.getRandomX()}
            cy={this.getRandomY()}
            r={this.randomRadius()}
            stroke="none"
            strokeWidth="0"
            fill="#CCCCCC"
            key={y}
            className="star"
        />
    ))}
    </svg>
</div>
```

If i use low values for width and height of viewBox, the stars appear zoomed in on my computer browser but look fine on mobile. If i use higher values, the stars look fine on computer but look zoomed out and only cover the screen partially on mobile. How can i make it consistent on both devices?

Comment: best to specify height and width as well as viewBox

Comment: @mukul Would you like to give me some feedback for my answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you don’t have `height` and `width` in your SVG. You have to specify `height`, `width` and `viewBox` like follows:

```
<svg id="sky"
  width="400"
  height="650"
  viewBox="0 0 400 650">
...
```